# Cannot format a macro

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, formatter

On eclipse CDT luna I want to auto format this:

```
case 1:
            MY_TRACE("bad case!");
            error = true;
            break;
```

When I do an auto format I get this:

```
case 1:
            MY_TRACE("bad case!")
            ;
            error = true;
            break;
```

But formatting is good for some other cases:

```
if (!error) {
    MY_TRACE("Good!");
```

Can I configure it or is it a bug?

Comment: Are you supposed to put `;` after the macro? Or does it already end with one?

Comment: It is a old code and people always put a ; , I've just tried with no ; and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Likely, your `MY_TRACE` macro expands to something that already ends with a `;`

Comment: Can we tell eclipse to auto format code as is, without expanding macros?